# Return number in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this Oracle SQL query which I use to count components into table:

```
 select ct.name as component_type, count(1) as cnt from componentstats cs, componenttype ct
WHERE CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID AND CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (1000, 1300, 4000)
group by ct.name  order by ct.name;
```

This is the output:

```
COMPONENT_TYPE                                                                                       CNT                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- 
DATACENTER                                                                                           1                      
ISP                                                                                                  1                      
NETWORK                                                                                              1
```

I noticed that if there is no component with type for example 1300 I get two values 1 and 1. I need to get result 1, 0, 1 because the order of the numbers must be strict. Can you tell me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer join for this.  This is a very good reason why you should use standard ANSI join syntax.

You also need to change the `count()` to count from the "outer" part of the outer join.  Here is the query written using `left outer join`:

```
select ct.name as component_type, count(cs.componenttypeid) as cnt
from componenttype ct left outer join
     componentstats cs
     on CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID
where CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN (1000, 1300, 4000)
group by ct.name
order by ct.name;
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing. How I can display only the numbers CNT without `name` as result?

Comment: @PeterPenzov . . . you and add `and cs.name = null` to the `where` clause.